# How can i change the value given a date from the user in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, search, replace, find

I'm new to C# and I'm currently working on a project of my own. Its a mortgage calculator and I'm currently trying to put together the amortization portion of it. If the user has no additional payments they would like to add in addition to the current monthly payment. The program iterates from the current date every month for however long the loan period is. However I want the program to be able to handle if the user would like to add a one time payment or an additional payment on a yearly basis.

Question 1: If the user wants to add an additional payment on a yearly basis how can I ask the user for what month of every year they would like this payment to fall on. And then from there how can it change the current value of that month so that it is original payment + additional yearly. The program would iterate normally with the addition of this information to show how much faster they can pay off their loan ect.

Question 2. If the user wants to add an additional one time payment how can I ask the user to give me a certain month and only change that months value. Again the program should run normally after this just showing how much that one, one time payment affects the overall duration of the loan, principle, and interest paid ect.

I'm not exactly sure how to start tackling this. This is what i have so far.

```
        else if (AdditionalYearly > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter date");
            var userInput = Console.ReadLine();
            DateTime result;
            //not sure how to get it to find the value given the date and 
             change it//
            MonthlyPayment = AdditionalYearly + MonthlyPayment;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Console.ReadLine() returns a string
You need to convert the string to a DateTime.
Use: DateTime.Parse(userInput) or DateTrime.TryParse

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parse?view=net-5.0
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparse?view=net-5.0

Ideally, you would want to use TryParse and let the user know if you can't parse the input.